# Oracle- Noforce

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Sql Developer to access a oracle database. Recently I created a View with the option NOFORCE `CREATE OR REPLACE NOFORCE VIEW XXXX (...)`
Afterwards I looked into the definition of the newly created view and I got a statement looking like `CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "name"."XXXX"`
Now I am not quite sure, if this is a wrong display setting for the Sql Developer or if the view is created with the force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just appears to be how Oracle handles views once they've been created, as you can see from the following example:

```
create or replace noforce view dummy_vw as select dummy from dual;

select * from user_views where view_name = 'DUMMY_VW';

VIEW_NAME TEXT_LENGTH TEXT                   TYPE_TEXT_LENGTH TYPE_TEXT OID_TEXT_LENGTH OID_TEXT VIEW_TYPE_OWNER VIEW_TYPE SUPERVIEW_NAME                 EDITIONING_VIEW READ_ONLY
--------- ----------- ---------------------- ---------------- --------- --------------- -------- --------------- --------- ------------------------------ --------------- ---------
DUMMY_VW           22 select dummy from dual                                                                                                              N               N        

select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW','DUMMY_VW') from DUAL;

  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "SCHEMA"."DUMMY_VW" ("DUMMY") AS 
  select dummy from dual;
```

Since force/noforce only affects the view at the point when it's created, it doesn't really matter if the script is returned with or without the FORCE keyword, so I guess they just defaulted it to show with the FORCE keyword, since the view exists (if the view script had errors and NOFORCE was used, the view wouldn't have been created).

Comment: Thank you, that contains more information, than our database admins was able to give. There the only answer was, I don't know, I don't care

Comment: It's probably one of those things that only the person who designed that bit of Oracle could answer, to be honest! You'll notice that if you create the view without the `or replace`, that is also added into the script returned by dbms_metadata.get_ddl.